# Python: Varied step size in range function

Tags: python-3.x, range

The below code outputs what I want, but I would like to know how to make it elegant, i.e., in a single: How can I elegantly/simply produce a vector of varying step sizes (for the purpose of binning an array)?

```
bins = [b for b in range(0,100,5)]
bins = numpy.append(bins, [b for b in range(100,200,10)]
bins = numpy.append(bins, [b for b in range(200,500,50)]
bins = numpy.append(bins, [b for b in range(500,2500,500)]
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Make a list of range options and then iterate over them?

```
bins = []
for r in (range(0,100,5), range(100,200,10), range(200,500,50), range(500,2500,500)):
    bins = numpy.append(bins, [b for b in r])
```

Or even neater by doing:

```
bins = []
for start, end, step in ((0,100,5), (100,200,10),(200,500,50), (500,2500,500)):
    bins = numpy.append(bins, [b for b in range(start, end,step)])
```

(*Note - this is a general-purpose answer - I'm not a `numpy` user so I don't know if there's a numpy-specific way of doing this more efficiently*).

Comment: Thank you @match! Much appreciated. That certainly tidies up my original code. Having come from previously coding in MATLAB, I would always try to remove all for loops. Even though it's not needed here, I think this could be a good learning example for myself. In case it is possible to remove all for loops I would e very interested!

Comment: I've collapsed this down further by just iterating over a tuple containing range params, and then calling range once (was in a rush before so didn't do this). Think that makes it a bit neater.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you very much @match